# How to add margin in the x axis in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

The rightmost bar overlaps with the y axis in the rihgt. How to add margin in the x axis to fix the problem?

[image: The rightmost bar overlaps with the y axis in the rihgt.]

Comment: [`plt.xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)? Or if using the object-oriented interface, [`ax.set_xlim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately it is still the case.

Comment: Please create a [reprex].